# Lining up headers and data in tables (html & css)

Tags: html, css, html-table

I was reading through a CSS [tutorial](https://learn.shayhowe.com/html-css/organizing-data-with-tables/) on tables and in one of the examples, the author creates a table that has borders on the `<td>` but no borders on `<th>`.

It seems that if you set the `border-collapse: collapse` the table headers don't align with the table body (there's space on the left and right sides where the border stretches too far).

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

thead {
  /* background: #395870; */
  /* color: #fff;*/
  background: #f0f0f2
}

tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #f0f0f2
}

td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cecfd5;
  border-right: 1px solid #cecfd5;
}

table td:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid #cecfd5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>your page title goes here</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <caption>Design and Front-End Development Books</caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col" colspan="2">Item</th>
        <th scope="col">Qty</th>
        <th scope="col">Price</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Don't Make me Think by Steve Krug</td>
        <td>In Stock</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>$30.02</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>A Project Guide to UX Design by Russ Unger & Carolyn Chandler</td>
      <td>In Stock</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>$52.94 ($26.47 x 2)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Introducing HTML5 by Bruce Lawson & Remy Sharp</td>
      <td>Out of Stock</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>$22.23</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bulletproof Web Design by Dan Cederholm</td>
      <td>In Stock</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>$30.17</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Subtotal</td>
        <td>$135.36</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Tax</td>
        <td>$13.54</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Total</td>
        <td>$148.90</td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

However, if you set `border-collapse: separate` `border-spacing: 0` then it ends up working properly as seen below.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

th, 
td {
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
thead {
  /* background: #395870; */
  /* color: #fff;*/
  background: #f0f0f2
} 
tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #f0f0f2
}
td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cecfd5;
  border-right:1px solid #cecfd5;
}
table td:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid #cecfd5;
}


/* The first td inside of each tr */

/* td:first-child {
  border-left: 1px solid #cecfd5;
} */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>your page title goes here</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <caption>Design and Front-End Development Books</caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col" colspan="2">Item</th>
        <th scope="col">Qty</th>
        <th scope="col">Price</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Don't Make me Think by Steve Krug</td>
        <td>In Stock</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>$30.02</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>A Project Guide to UX Design by Russ Unger & Carolyn Chandler</td>
        <td>In Stock</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>$52.94 ($26.47 x 2)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Introducing HTML5 by Bruce Lawson & Remy Sharp</td>
        <td>Out of Stock</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>$22.23</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Bulletproof Web Design by Dan Cederholm</td>
        <td>In Stock</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>$30.17</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Subtotal</td>
        <td>$135.36</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Tax</td>
        <td>$13.54</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Total</td>
        <td>$148.90</td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not entirely sure why this happens. Would be great if someone could explain how this is working.

Comment: Is the effect shown in the snippets? I don't see any difference. (And not sure what you're alluding to.) Edit: I think I see a slight difference on the LH side. IDK the diff b/t collapse and separate off hand.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any difference. Use `border-color: 'black'`  to see any change if you encounter.

For reference:[border-seperate Vs border-collapse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse)`